ASP.NET Core Integration Testing IPasswordHasher<T>.HashPassword Generates Different Hashes
I'm integration testing my ASP.NET Core app, specifically the sign-in actions, and I'm running into an issue where IPasswordHasher<T>.HashPassword() is generating different hashes between my test's setup and the action's execution, and I don't know what to do about it.
Currently, my test first creates a user, hashes the password using HashPassword(null!, password), and then saves it to the database and returns the user and the un-hashed password. Then I take that and create the form data to give to HttpClient to POST to the action. All of that works correctly, with the only difference being that when the user is created before the test, the hash that is generated is different from the hash that is generated when checking the user in the action.
The only thing I can think of is that since IPasswordHasher<T> is a scoped dependency, the scope I create for creating the user before the test is different from the scope created for the action, and thus two different instances and possibly two different random number generators for each instance?
For the time being I'm working around it by removing all registrations for IPasswordHasher<T> and the registering it again with my own MockPasswordHasher<T> implementation which just gets the hash code of the password and returns it as a string. While that works, it makes me warry that I'm deviating from the original app being tested because what will be published will be different, and thus maybe my integration tests will be faulty.
internal sealed class MockPasswordHasher<TUser> :
    PasswordHasher<TUser>
    where TUser : class {
    public override string HashPassword(
        TUser user,
        string password) => password.GetHashCode().ToString();
}

Is there a proper way from me to overcome this or is the mock password hasher I'm registering the way to go?

Some password-hashing algorithms do not generate determinstic output, this is for security (e.g. so if the DB is leaked, people won't be able to see which users are sharing the same password because their hashes are the same), e.g. with a random salt. So this could all be by-design.

@Dai, you're right. When you said it could be by design, it made me rethink my implementation, and I have now found the solution. Take a look at my answer below. Thank you!

After @Dai said that it could be by design, I took a look at my implementation again and I realized that it may not actually be wrong, it's just that my usage of IPasswordHasher<T> is wrong. I was creating the user before the test, hashing the password, saving to the database, and then passing the user's credentials to the action. This is all good, but in the action's downstream handler I was getting the password and hashing it again, and then passing that to the database lookup, which never found the user. That is where the problem lies.
I realized that I'm not using the VerifyPasswordHash() method on the hasher. So, I removed the password hash comparison from the database queries, and returned the user's password that was in the database. I then passed it as the expected hash along with the supplied password to the verification method, and it worked exactly as expected.
I can now remove the mock password hasher, not concern myself with instances, and actually have confidence in my tests.
Thank you @Dai!

Thank you @Dai! - always appreciated
